# Branch.io remove redirect from click URL with parameter query

Tags: ads, branch.io

I would like to stop the click URL from redirecting to the landing page. Other MMPs have this documented and you can simply append the URL with an appropriate parameter like the following:

> Appsflyer: redirect=false
>
> Adjust: redirect=none
>
> Kochava: pbr=1

How do I accomplish the same thing in Branch.io? I would have checked this documentation but since Branch.io updated their site, the documentation I'm looking for appears to no longer exist:

https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000216765

Comment: If you watch into the html there's an element <input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="https://branch.io">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding your query that you do not want the link to be redirected to a landing page, you can append **$s2s=true** to the link to get the same behaviour as you are receiving from other MMPs.

Currently Branch is updating the documentation to as to be more user-friendly and focused towards fetching content easily. Would request you to check out help.branch.io for more information.

Thanks